# I'm successfully upload image to Firebase database BUT when i try to open image Url i got this message

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I've successfully upload image to Firebase database BUT when i try to open image Url i got this message

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}
```

and this is the code ...

```
var uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName).putBytes(data)
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            Toast.makeText(this, "Upload failed, try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {

            val downloadUrl = it.toString()

            // taskSnapshot.metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
            // ...
            val intent = Intent(this, ChooseUserActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("imageName", imageName)
            intent.putExtra("imageUrl", downloadUrl)
            intent.putExtra("message", messageEditText?.text.toString() )
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Comment: please add your firestore rules here thinks rules are not allowed for downloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I solved the problem by edit a code and some to it .. and the final code is ..

```
 var uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName).putBytes(data)
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        Toast.makeText(this, "Upload failed, try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }.addOnSuccessListener {

        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName)
        ref.downloadUrl
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val downloadUrl = task.result
                    // taskSnapshot.metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
                    // ...
                    val intent = Intent(this, ChooseUserActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("imageName", imageName)
                    intent.putExtra("imageUrl", downloadUrl.toString())
                    intent.putExtra("message", messageEditText?.text.toString())
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

            }
    }
```